# How to define the height of a row when using CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css, grid, grid-layout, css-grid

I've managed to create a very simple layout so that the `<div class="content">` fills to the remaining available height.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">HEADER</div>
        <div class="nav">NAV</div>
        <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

In the feature, i could add a new row, like so

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="nav">NAV</div>
    <div class="filter">FILTER</div>
    <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

And then, i will need to change again the CSS

```
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr auto;
```

So, is there a way to tell CSS to make all of the rows `auto`, including those added in the future, but just keep `<div class="content">` to `1fr`

That way i can add rows dynamically without the need to keep changing the css.
Thanks

Comment: There's really no way to target a row in a grid container based on a grid item's attributes. But since you're working with a single-column grid, why not use flexbox? It's clean and simple. https://jsfiddle.net/5ms30dwr/